# Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь реализовать поиск данных из таблицы patient. Суть в следующем: Есть 3 поля (Фамилия, Имя, Отчество). Поиск должен происходить по заполненным полям, но как это сделать пока не могу разобраться. Пока что сделал только для одного поля.

Класс Patient

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
@Indexed
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "fam")
    private String fam;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "im")
    private String im;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "ot")
    private String ot;
    
    @Column(name = "bdate")
    private Date bdate;
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private int sex;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "mail")
    private String mail;
    @Column(name = "snils")
    private String snils;
    @Column(name = "createdate")
    private Date createdate;

    public Patient() {

    }

    public Patient(String fam, String im, String ot, Date bdate, int sex, String phone, String mail, String snils, Date createdate) {
        this.fam = fam;
        this.im = im;
        this.ot = ot;
        this.bdate = bdate;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.snils = snils;
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFam() {
        return fam;
    }

    public void setFam(String fam) {
        this.fam = fam;
    }

    public String getIm() {
        return im;
    }

    public void setIm(String im) {
        this.im = im;
    }

    public String getOt() {
        return ot;
    }

    public void setOt(String ot) {
        this.ot = ot;
    }

    public Date getBdate() {
        return bdate;
    }

    public void setBdate(Date bdate) {
        this.bdate = bdate;
    }

    public int getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(int sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getSnils() {
        return snils;
    }

    public void setSnils(String snils) {
        this.snils = snils;
    }

    public Date getCreatedate() {
        return createdate;
    }

    public void setCreatedate(Date createdate) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }
}
```

Метод для поиска

```
private void testSearch()  {

    Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(session);
    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Patient.class).get();

    Query query = queryBuilder
            .keyword()
            .wildcard()
            .onFields("fam")
            .matching(txtFieldFam.getText().trim() + "*")
            .createQuery();

    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Patient.class);

    List<Patient> list = fullTextQuery.getResultList();

    for (Patient p: list
         ) {
        System.out.println(p.getFam() + " / " + p.getIm());
    }
}
```

Comment: кто-либо сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 0):

Если в вашем приложении используется `Spring` то первое что я рекомендую это использовать его стандартные репозитории, которые предоставляет `Spring Data JPA`, вместо способа создания запросов, который используете вы. Для ваших нужд вам необходимо будет создать интерфейс репозитория, например, `PatientRepository` который должен наследовать интерфейс `JpaRepository<T, ID>`, где `T` - это тип сохраняемой сущности, `ID` - класс, который представляет первичный ключ в сущности. `JpaRepository` уже будет иметь реализацию всех `CRUD` операций для вашей сущности. Теперь конкретно по вашему методу, у `JpaRepository` есть замечательный способ создания запросов из имен методов интерфейсов. Вот пример для вашего случая:

```
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Integer> {
    List<Patient> findByFamOrImOrOtContaining(String searchString);
}
```

Метод аналогичен SQL-скрипту:

```
SELECT * FROM patient WHERE fam like '%searchString%' OR im like '%searchString%' OR ot like '%searchString%'
```

За более подробной информацией обращайтесь к [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories).

Теперь относительно вашего кода. Не используйте примитивы для полей в сущностях `Hibernate`, поля должны допускать значение `null` если они не заданы, в случае примитива у вас там будет значение по умолчанию. Используйте нормальные имена переменных чтобы сразу было понятно для чего оно используется. В вашем случае, уж простите названия просто ужасны `fam`, `im` и `ot`. Они абсолютно не читабельны и не используйте транслит русских слов на латиницу, если возможно переменную назвать на английском: `surName`, `firsName`, `patronymic`. Русский транслит это уж очень крайний случай.
Надеюсь мой ответ вам будет полезен.

PS. Также чтобы избавиться от кучи шаблонного кода советую вам почитать о проекте [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Это пока что тестовый проект, согласен что использовать такие имена не хорошо. Если я правильно понимаю вас в классе Patient вместо int лучше использовать Integer, чтобы была возможность искать по null? Spring не используется у меня в проекте. Я хочу написать небольшое приложение, которое будет работать с Postgree посредством Hibernate. Какой способ предпочтительнее использовать HQL для написания запросов или наткнулся на такую штуку как Hibernate Search, что лучше?

Comment: Если вы будете искать только по трем полям ФИО, то это не сложная задача и вы можете реализовать это на HQL, а вот Hibernate Search это уже более серьезная штука, я с ним не работал, но если хотите можете юзать и ее для ваших нужд. Вот тут https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/hibernate-search  не плохо описаны примеры запросов.

Comment: Я пробовал на HQL так: public List<Patient> findPatientsWithParams(String fam, String im, String ot) {
 List<Patient> patientList = (List<Patient>) HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()
   .createQuery("from Patient where (:fam is null or fam like:fam) and (im=:im or :im is null) and (ot=:ot or :ot is null)").setParameter("fam", fam)
 .setParameter("im", im)
   .setParameter("ot", ot)
   .setMaxResults(100)
   .list();
 return patientList;
}.   Но когда например пользователь вводит данные только в поле ot, то ничего не находит, хотя в БД есть с таким отчеством.

Comment: Не находит, потому что условия объединены через AND, а нужно через OR. Т.е. вы говорите найди мне совпадения с моим запросом в фамилии, имени и отчестве. И если хоть что-то не даст тру, то все выражение будет фолс. А через ОR вы получите истину когда будет совпадение даже только по одному из полей.

Comment: OR не подходит. Мне нужно так: Если ввели данные только в одно поле, то искать по этому полю и остальные игнорировать как будто эти параметры null. Если использовать OR будут найдены и те кто не попадает под условие, если использовать AND и ввести например только фамилию никого не находит потому что условие такое where fam like:fam and im like:im and ot like:ot. При OR если ввести фамилию и отчество найдутся все у кого отчество и фамилия совпадают с fam и ot, а мне же нужно чтобы если ввели fam и ot искать только таких у кого фамилия и отчество такие.

Comment: Т.е. предположим у вас будет метод который принимает на вход три параметра, которые могут быть не обязательными. Поиск нужно производить только по тем полям, которые не были пустыми, верно я понял?

Comment: Да, метод будет принимать три параметра (int для поля id и два типа String для полей fam и ot). Данные пользователь будет вводить в текстовые поля.

Comment: В таком случае я предлагаю вам не писать универсальный запрос под все понял, а создать строку динамически на основании только тех полей что были введены, т.е. если будет только имя введено, то и строка с поиском будет `FROM Patient WHERE im LIKE :im`, а вот если имя и фамилия не пусты, то `FROM Patient WHERE im LIKE :im AND fam LIKE :fam`. Т.е. у вас будет несколько простых запросов для различных критериев поиска, а вот какой выбрать вы уже решите на основании введенных пользователем данных.

Comment: Я уже сделал используя параметры, Ваша идея хорошая, попробую такой вариант тоже. Что-то не подумал сразу об этом. Спасибо.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь =)